# Windows 8 Metro style Fonts for arabic

Tags: windows-8, fonts, microsoft-metro, arabic

I searched for the fonts used in windows 8 modern metro style i found segeo but it appears different in arabic characters than that on windows 8, i'm using windows 7.

simply i want to get all fonts of win 8 segeo (new version) and the one used for arabic in this image
[image]

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found they are segoe ui light the same as english but the version coming with windows 8 not same one in windows 7. you can copy them from windows 8 from the fonts folder any segoe font to your fonts folder and replace old.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about how to upgrade the font and included the new fonts as a download http://www.amreldib.com/2013/08/UpgradeWindowsFontForBetterArabicReadability.html

Comment: @Amr Can I use this font for my web application? If the license doesn't permit so, can I buy it?

Comment: I don't think so. There a lot of free Arabic fonts. Here are some: http://www.google.com/fonts